# can imap_search search with "subject" and "UNSEEN"?

Tags: php, imap

is it possible search with
"subject" and "UNSEEN" using `imap_search` ? If yes,please reply. Thank you

Comment: Refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

Comment: Yes it;s possible..  for UnSEEn

Comment: Do you want someone to reply if 'no'? If not how will you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to search email messages according to their subject and unseen criteria using **[imap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php)**.

Following is prototype of imap_search function

```
array imap_search ( resource $imap_stream , string $criteria 
[, int $options = SE_FREE [, string $charset = NULL ]] )
```

where **$imap_stream** is resource to imap server connection
and **criteria** filters email messages.

To search email messages on basis of their subject and unseen criteria
please try executing following code snippet.

```
define('IMAP_HOST', '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX');
define('IMAP_USER', 'USERNAME');
define('IMAP_PWD', 'PWD');
$imap_stream = imap_open(IMAP_HOST, IMAP_USER, IMAP_PWD) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($imap_stream, 'SUBJECT my subject UNSEEN');
```

Comment: I have one more problem, Code is working fine on localhost, but online linux  server is not working. What is problem. thank you.

Comment: @sandy Will you please describe error occuring while execution of script on online linux server

Comment: [0] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
    [1] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
    [2] => Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco

and 
imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox in ...

Comment: I also already enable "--with-imap-ssl", "IMAP c-Client Version:2007f", SSL Support:enabled", "Kerberos Support:enabled"

Comment: I also tried "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox"
and

 "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX"
But still no luck.

Comment: Did you search for that error? There are literally dozens of questions about connecting to gmail.

Comment: I didn't get any solution, who can solve my problem? do you have any solution. plz help. @Max

Comment: Did you enable less secure application or generate an app specific password?

Answer (score 0):

docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.fetch

You can use following methods to fetch mails by subject, id, unseen or from any folder.

Comment: atleast he will get idea from this

Comment: I have removed all the stuff and start again from beginning. its working now. thankyou every one for reply. :D